# How should i test a super(xy) call?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I just want to write for this piece of code a unittest:

```
public class MyClass extends SomeClassICanNotChange {

    public MyClass(SomeObjectThatTheSuperClassNeed param) {
        super(param);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean thisMethodIWantToTest() {
         return true; // Some magic here
    }
```

Some limitations:

- I can't change the superclass `SomeClassICanNotChange`.
- It is necessary to call `super(param)`
- The superclass `SomeClassICanNotChange` do some stuff with the `param`, so just `Mockito.mock(SomeObjectThatTheSuperClassNeed.class)` won't work (NPE).

I want to test the method `thisMethodIWantToTest()`. My only idea is to mock all methods the super class need. Somethink like this: `Mockito.when(myMock.xy()).thenReturn(..)`. But this seems not very smart.

Does anyone know a better way to write this UnitTest?

Thank you very much

Comment: if you want to test the superclass, you could always just create a completely separate test suite just for testing that class, separate from any code you extend it with in your derived class. it's common to write tests just for 3rd party libraries you integrate with and it also helps you to confirm your usage of that code.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I don't want to test the superclass. In my unittest I just want to test the method `thisMethodIWantToTest()`.

But thanks for the hint to test the 3rd party lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `thisMethodIWantToTest)(` does not need `SomeObjectThatTheSuperClassNeed` to serve its purpose, you can, maybe even should, decouple it from `MyClass` to a seperate type. -> If a type needs another type just for it's creation but doesn't need it to serve its purpose, then it's bad design.

If `thisMethodIWantToTest` needs `SomeObjectThatTheSuperClassNeed`, then it's on one hand an unflattering design, because it mixes abstraction with implementation, which makes things way too complicated. On the other hand, you could either pass the real implementation and test it implicit (not that great either), or you DO mock `SomeObjectThatTheSuperClassNeed` and provide the mock for other test cases, too.

But anyway, if it's hard to test something, it's a sign for a design flaw. You either change it now, which I assume you can't, or, my best guess is you go with the decoupling to the separate type...

Comment: Thank you for this hint.